# Struts2 radio button list, divide list by index

Tags: list, struts2, radio-button

I have list named `options` and I want to print two radio list by separating options list by index value, mostly middle one or let's see at index 5

```
<s:radio     list = "options"
          listKey = "optionId" 
        listValue = "optionText" 
             name = "selectedlist"  
            label = "optionText" 
            value = "optionId" />
```

How can I print two radio list by separating lists? I want to use `<s:radio/>` tag two times using same list just by using half in first and another half in second. I can divide list in action itself and pass it, but is there any `<s:radio/>` tag specific solution?

Comment: You can use `<s:iterator>` tag to iterate elements and create whatever layout you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be done serverside, not in the view.

For the evilness (and untestedness), you could use [`public List<E> subList(int fromIndex, int toIndex)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/AbstractList.html#subList%28int,%20int%29)

```
<s:radio     list = "options.subList(0 , options.size() / 2)"
          listKey = "optionId" 
        listValue = "optionText" 
             name = "selectedlist"  
            label = "optionText" 
            value = "optionId" />
```

and

```
<s:radio     list = "options.subList(options.size() / 2 , options.size())"
          listKey = "optionId" 
        listValue = "optionText" 
             name = "selectedlist"  
            label = "optionText" 
            value = "optionId" />
```

But don't be evil. Do it serverside.

Comment: Right, won't be evil, it's just pretty cool to know more ways. :) thanks